# OS X Kills processes that fork too quickly?

Tags: macos, operating-system, fork, osx-elcapitan

I'm a TA for an operating systems class where the students are tasked with developing a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) defuser.  As part of the test cases I wanted to develop something that looked like a fork bomb, but was in fact fairly safe (i.e. spawns off many processes, but those processes are removed).  My question is that on testing this on my OS X machine I noticed that it actually kills all my user processes if I set the usleep delay too low(~100000) and the number of children too high(~1000).  When I say all I mean Firefox, Xcode, Word, even Finder seems to go down.  This seems somewhat strange to me, as the task only ever has one child, but I am wondering if OS X has a limit to the number of child processes a user can have.  I wasn't able to find anything on google, but any suggestions are appreciated.

In particular:
1) Is this code unreasonable and I'm missing some obvious reason it should be killed?
2) Is there some documentation in OS X that might explain the reason we are seeing this behavior?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    pid_t pid;

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: fork_safe n\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            break;
        } else {
            printf("child pid %d, killing...\n", pid);
            usleep(10000);
            kill(pid,SIGTERM);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to ask this on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking the return value from `fork()` for error.  And if it returns `-1`, you're passing -1 into the `kill` function.

And according to the [man page for the kill function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

> If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the
>   calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1
>   (init), but see below.

So I suspect that `fork` fails when it can't allocate any more processes.  Thereby, your code is sending a SIGTERM to EVERY process your account owns.  That explains the behavior you are seeing.

Modify your for-loop accordingly:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (pid == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate any more processes\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("child pid %d, killing...\n", pid);
        usleep(10000);
        kill(pid,SIGTERM);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh geez, can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks for the quick reply!  It does seem that fork is returning -1, adding that catch seems to have solved the problem. Additionally "ulimit -u" shows 709, which is close to the 613 I get. Thanks!